# Problema al cambiar ip en Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, servidor, redes

Soy nueva en `linux` y levante mi servidor `apache` `tomcat` en una máquina virtual de `virtualvox` con `Ubuntu Server`, ahora quiero acceder al servidor desde otra maquina virtual, para eso necesito cambiar mi `ip`.
Realise esto.
**1.** `Sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

**2.**

```
Iface enp0s3 inet static.            
address 192.168.1.15.              
netmask 255.255.255.0.            
gateway 192.168.1.1.           
network 192.168.1.0.          
broadcast 192.168.1.255.            
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

**3.** `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Acá me sale el error no puedo reiniciar mi `ip` y al ejecutar `ifconfig` mi `ip` es la anterior

Comment: Depende de cómo has definido las propiedades de la máquina virtual. Debes asegurarte de tener el adaptador de red en el modo correcto para tu interés.

Comment: Estaba en red nat y tambien probe con adaptador puente pero el resultado es el mismo

Comment: Pon el error que te da para ver si es un problema de sintaxis. De primeras veo que pones un . al final de cada línea, y me da que eso no es correcto

Comment: Para conectar las dos maquinas virtuales el adaptador de red lo debes colocar en Host-only y que las diferentes maquinas virtuales tengan configurado el mismo adaptador de red.

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes utilizar la interfaz ejecutando el comando "yast" o puedes ejecutar el comando service network restart

Cuéntame como te va y si se corrigió

Comment: Te invito a que leas: [answer] y [No tengo reputación para dejar un comentario, pero quiero decir algo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3765/107347)